# woocommerce empty cart via api not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm building an SPA using wordpress and woocommerce. Everything works fine (displaying products, handling payments, etc), except for emptying the user's cart after payment is complete. I wrote most endpoints custom.

In my payment handling endpoint, I wrote `WC()->cart->empty_cart()` after successful payments. This seems to work when I check `WC()->cart->get_cart` before and after emptying it (it's full before, empty after), however, when I subsequently open my cart modal (also using `WC()->cart->get_cart()`, but via a GET request), the items are still in there. If I complete the checkout via the woocommerce standard checkout pages instead of the SPA the cart empties just fine.

I know there are some other questions on this forum regarding this issue, but none of the solutions work for me. I tried `WC()->cart->empty_cart(true)` and setting 'cart' in the `WC()->session` to an empty array. I don't really know where else the cart is stored, or how WC()->cart accesses this information, but I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that I'm trying to empty via an asynchronous request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this problem only occurred for logged in users. There is a persistent cart for logged in users, that is supposed to be cleared when `true` is passed into `empty_cart` (default). However, since this request is made via API, the wordpress function `get_current_user_id` that is used by `empty_cart` returns 0 because it doesn't have access to the correct user global on the server. This can be solved by  adding a wordpress nonce in the headers of the ajax request to make the user available to the server. When this nonce is supplied, the aforementioned function to clear the cart works just fine. More info about nonces: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Teuween: does that mean te issue is solved? if so, please mark your own answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP call too `WC()->cart->empty_cart()` won't magically call the frontend work which is needed to refresh the HTML.
to update the HTML you would have to do something like

`jQuery(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');`

Feel free to check `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments.js` and see what it actually does.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I first make an API call to my own payment endpoint, at the end of which I empty the cart (and check that it's truly empty using WC()->cart->get_cart()). Next, on the same webpage, I refresh my cart contents using a GET request to another custom endpoint. Both use the same function to get cart contents, but the first one returns an empty cart, whereas the second returns the cart with the items that I originally was trying to remove. Since I'm refreshing the cart contents, I'm not sure what you mean by 'frontend work'?